# FreeRTOS - vTaskList undefined reference

Tags: task, freertos, rtos

I am trying to use vTaskList function to monitor tasks being used.
In order to use vTaskList, I configure the macro below.

```
#define configUSE_TRACE_FACILITY        1
#define configUSE_STATS_FORMATTING_FUNCTIONS 1
```

and below is task code to display task list.

```c
  void TASK_LIST()
    {
        signed char pWriteBuffer[2048];
        for(;;)
        {
            vTaskList(pWriteBuffer);
            printf("task_name   task_state  priority   stack  tasK_num\n");
            printf("%s\n", pWriteBuffer);
        }
        vTaskDelete(NULL);
        return;
    }
```

However, the error just showed up for undefined reference

What caused this error?

Thank you.

> Ps. For my original situation, there is no macro for
>   configUSE_STATS_FORMATTING_FUNCTIONS in FreeRTOSConfig.h. so I add it
>   manually.

Now I am searching building command to build whole project
[image]

Comment: Could you paste the error message verbatim?

Comment: undefined reference to `vTaskList' main.c line 268 C/C++ Problem

Comment: Do you include task.h ?

Comment: What is the version of FreeRTOS that you are using? I found some source code for v10 and it requires configSUPPORT_DYNAMIC_ALLOCATION to be enabled as well

Comment: Yes, I have included task.h
FreeRTOS is v7.5.3

Answer (score 1):

It looks from code source as it depends on FreeRTOS kernel version...

I checked several demo applications for your particular version, e.g. [this one](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/freertos/code/tags/V7.5.3/FreeRTOS/Demo/WizNET_DEMO_TERN_186/), and also code source for *tasks.c*. And it should be enough to set those two macros which you mentioned. So, the actual reason of linking error looks like not related to configuration itself. Check if *tasks.c* source file is rebuilt after configuration change (if not, dependencies in project are not handled properly). Double check also that those defines are real "**1**" - digit (not "**l**" (small "L" letter) or "**I**" (capital "I" letter), which can be easily confused with "1" depending on used font).

**UPDATE**

Since you are using Eclipse IDE, take a look at this [official guidance of how to setup project](https://www.freertos.org/Project_Workspace_Relative_File_Paths_Eclipse.html). [Here](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/freertos/code/tags/V7.5.3/FreeRTOS/Demo/CORTEX_LM3Sxxxx_Eclipse/) you can find demo project for Eclipse for your version of FreeRTOS, check [Makefile](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/freertos/code/tags/V7.5.3/FreeRTOS/Demo/CORTEX_LM3Sxxxx_Eclipse/RTOSDemo/Makefile) in particular, I guess your auto-generated Makefile missing lines like:

```
$(RTOS_SOURCE_DIR)/tasks.c \
```

**PS**

For [v9.0.0](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/freertos/code/tags/V9.0.0/FreeRTOS/Source/tasks.c) it should be enough to enable configurations as you did. But [v10.0.0](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/freertos/code/tags/V10.0.0/FreeRTOS/Source/tasks.c) there is also dependency on **configSUPPORT_DYNAMIC_ALLOCATION**: if in project's *FreeRTOSConfig.h* it's defined to something other than default ("1") - vTaskList will be excluded. This dependency, however, is neither mentioned in include header file task.h nor in [online documentation](https://www.freertos.org/a00021.html#vTaskList).

Comment: My FreeRTOS is v7.5.3.
I have also checked the documentation. I still don't get it...

Comment: @黃銘賢 but 7.5.3 has configUSE_STATS_FORMATTING_FUNCTIONS 
https://svn.code.sf.net/p/freertos/code/tags/V7.5.3/FreeRTOS/Source/include/FreeRTOS.h did you mean configUSE_TRACE_FACILITY instead?

Comment: Yes I found it.
However, even though I change the configuration in FreeRTOS.h
It showed up the same error.
Maybe I should include FreeRTOSConfig.h in task.c ?

Comment: @黃銘賢 no, you shouldn't modify files in kernel, but it looks like your changes in  FreeRTOSConfig.h are not applied for some reason. What if you just for test comment out #define configUSE_PREEMPTION for example - you should get compile error

Comment: Yes, I've tried to comment  #define configUSE_PREEMPTION.
And I get compiled error

Comment: @黃銘賢 OK, then a new thought: are you sure tasks.c is re-compiled, can you build from scratch?? i.e. remove object files and run build, can you find tasks.o ?

Comment: Yes, there are only files in src built.
I think this is the main problem that I can't use those functions

Comment: @黃銘賢 then it's a project setup issue, not FreeRTOS... you should describe which IDE you are using and how you are building

Comment: Now I am using eclipse IDE and I use the build tool inside.
In debug configuration, I enable "auto build".

Comment: However, as what you have said, there were not all file built.

Comment: Hello, I have checked makerfile in demo project. However, it seems different to mine. Besides, mine is autogenerated and the instruction is don't edit it. Can I just configure build path in Eclipse?

Comment: @黃銘賢 Have you checked https://www.freertos.org/Project_Workspace_Relative_File_Paths_Eclipse.html ? It's important to setup FREERTOS_ROOT path variable. And if you already generated Makefile - you can compare with https://svn.code.sf.net/p/freertos/code/tags/V7.5.3/FreeRTOS/Demo/CORTEX_LM3Sxxxx_Eclipse/RTOSDemo/Makefile - does it have $(RTOS_SOURCE_DIR)/tasks.c ?